# Still having trouble with crashes when composing answers in Chrome

Tags: bug, google-chrome

I don't know if this is true for other people, but I am still experiencing at least some of the problems described [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/annoying-bugs-when-using-chrome) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/showstopper-bug-msemathjax-unusable-for-2-months-with-chrome-17-18-latest), namely that Chrome crashes when I try to write answers that are too long. This also happens to me on MO sometimes.

This is annoying but not too bad when I'm writing an answer for the first time (I can usually recover the answer using the back button, but the longer the answer gets the more likely Chrome is to crash again), but when I'm *editing* an answer I lose all of my work when this happens. Also, even when I don't lose all my work while editing, there is a lot of lag.

I'm using Chrome with several extensions, but I generally don't have many tabs open at one time; maybe 3 or 4.

**Edit (10/31/12):** This remains an issue and remains annoying.

**Edit (11/10/12):** The situation has gotten a little worse. Chrome is now freezing instead of crashing.

Comment: I have crashes too, and was forced to switch back to Firefox

Comment: My experience exactly. Outcome: switched to FF. (But before the switch, I worked around this by composing answers in a notepad-like Chrome extension, then pasting to the answer field.)

Comment: Same here, still having the problems.

Comment: I use Chrome as well. Can you provide a link to a specific post? I want to click edit & see whether my browser will crash or not.

Comment: Chrome fails to me as well

Comment: I have crashes all the time (if I write question more then 3-5 min in one moment it simply doesn't respond for any mouse click. (and this happens in other my browsers FF and Iron).

Comment: I noticed that the crashes usually occurred when my answers had larger amounts of TeX which was continually being rendered, so I started to use robjohn's [bookmark](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) to disable rendering while I type long edits.

Comment: Exactly same experience here (since ages, I've commented in the old threads). My Chrome crashes often, and I've seen that same behaviour: when I edit an existing post and it crashes, I miss everything. It has just happen to me now, and I've lost a lot of typing. I love SE but this is very frustrating.

Comment: I am having problems as well.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again!

Comment: Still having crashes, and have lost countless hours of work.

Comment: I have crashes with Chrome and Windows 7. Mostly I do answers or comments and have been able to recover my work.

Comment: @Q The freezing may be due to a corrupted cache or some other state corrupted by the crashes. I vaguely recall getting into this state and having to either clear some cache or reinstall.

Comment: It's frustrating that there is no obvious evidence that anyone who would have power to do something about this knows, cares, or is working on it.

Comment: @Hurkyl: my understanding is that no one in power has been able to reproduce this error, which makes it hard to diagnose on their end.

Comment: Same for me. When editing existing answer tab completely freezes, while the other tabs are still working. Chrome version 23.0.1271.97