# MSE getting stuck

Tags: support, soft-question, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Still having trouble with crashes when composing answers in Chrome](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/still-having-trouble-with-crashes-when-composing-answers-in-chrome)

Probably, this is a problem with my machine or at least I hope so. Sometimes, MSE sometimes freezes whenever I am typing up a long answer. This has been quite frequent today. I was just typing up some answer, and it freezed at least 3 times, which made me retype all that stuff again and again. My browser is Chrome. It is windows 7. This doesn't happen to anyother tabs open. Please tell me what more additional information I should give.

Comment: This is a known problem when using MathJax on Chrome, e.g. search meta for "Chrome". Unfortunately it does not look like it will be fixed (a MathJax developer says the bug is in Chrome). Perhaps some day someone will figure out how to tweak MathJax to avoid the problem. Till then, the only way to avoid the Chrome freezes and crashes  is to use another browser when composing long answers. I've lost so much work due to this that I don't even dare to use Chrome any more on MSE. That's a shame, since Chrome is far faster for MSE than all other browsers